# Appending every second row to the first row in a dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe (created from an excel sheet) where every second row needs to be appended to the end of the first row.

For example -

```
Data in Row 1 = A B C D E ... AK (i.e. the number of columns in the first row is 37)

Data in Row 2 = a b c d e ... l (i.e. the number of columns in the second row is 12)

Data in Row 3 = A B C D E ... AK

Data in Row 4 = a b c d e ... l
```

etc.

The number of rows is variable (depending on the content of the original spreadsheet) but the number of columns is always the same.

**I need row n+1 to be appended to the end of row n resulting in row n having 49 columns of data.**

The new rows would look like this -

```
Row 1 = A B C D E ... AK a b c d e ... l

Row 2 = A B C D E ... AK a b c d e ... l
```

etc.

The final array will have half the number of rows we started out with.

I think the solution lies in the use of 'reshape' and 'arange', but I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: try `pd.concat(
    [df.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True), df.iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1
)` failing that please print the top 10 rows of your dataframe and paste it into your question.

Comment: Awesome, just as a good practice exercise, can you re-format your question and then answer the question using the code above to benefit others? I'll up vote you when you do both. for your question you should have 5-10 rows that someone else can reproduce in their own code editor, as well as what you expect the data to look like. For the answer just show and explain the code with a sample output. Welcome to SO:)

Comment: Noted.  Sorry, I wasn't familiar with the formatting when setting the question.  I'll try and upload some actual data to show it working.  Thanks again